# Pyinstaller --onefile ImportError: No module named 'win32api'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

**Problem statement:**

I can't seem to run

```
'PyInstaller --onefile myfile.py'
```

on a file containing

```
import wmi
```

It cannot find win32api. I get a popup warning saying python has stopped etc. My console says "ImportError: No module named 'win32api'". I can run 'import win32api', 'import win32com', and 'import WMI' in python directly in the same environment without issue. I fundamentally don't understand what is wrong here.

**Error message:**

```
3469 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
ImportError: No module named 'win32api'
```

**I have tried:**

[PyInstaller - ImportError: No module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421448/pyinstaller-importerror-no-module-named-win32api) - 'import os' works fine for PyInstaller and runs fine in python.

[No module named 'win32api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314463/no-module-named-win32api) - Not very helpful

[How to install pywin32 module in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863056/how-to-install-pywin32-module-in-windows-7/17061853#17061853) - This is where I got the SF link (python3.5 amd64 pywin32 version)

[ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343774/importerror-no-module-named-win32api) -
 I thought it might be a path thing, but my installation *appears* to be in the correct place: "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs\pywin32-220-py35_2\Lib\site-packages\win32"

I can run 'PyInstaller --onefile myscript.py' on other files, and have without issue as long as they don't use the wmi module.

I looked at the win32com _init__.py line 5 where it's messing up and it's just an import statement for win32api.

**System:**

Windows 7 x64, Python 3.5.3 64bit, Anaconda 4.3.14 64bit, using pyinstaller 3.2.3 (recommended by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728108/running-pyinstaller-after-anaconda-install-results-in-importerror-no-module-nam)), with pywin32 220 (with sourceforge download [I know, I tried pip, conda, and easy_install]) and I'm running it in cmder as an admin.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I couldn't use the module in the python shell, even if original one could. When I execute python shell as an administrator option, it was solved. Try it with administrator execution. I used python version 3.5.2 with windows x64bits.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem but I install  ---> pip install pypiwin32 to solve my problems

Comment: yeah the question is how to port it to the pyinstalled exe